# Open subset in the flat topology on Spec(R)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $S \subset \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a subset. Suppose that for each $P \in S$ there exists a Zariski open neighborhood $U$ of $P_P \in \mathrm{Spec}(R_P)$ such that $^aj_{P}(U) \subset S$, where $j_{P}:R \rightarrow R_{P}$ is the canonical morphism; so $S$ can be covered by images of Zariski open subsets under flat morphisms. Is it true that $S$ is open in the flat topology on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$? If not, is there any useful topology on $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ where $S$ is open?

Comment: The flat "topology" is not a topology in the classical sense...

Comment: A delicate aspect. I know that as a Grothendieck topology I would have to consider jointly surjective flat morphisms (+ some properties perhaps). But in "Going-down implies generalized going-down" by Dobbs--Hetzel (Lemma 2.1) there is a topology (in the "classical" sense) on Spec(R) defined (but this should have been considered before), which I thought is also referred to as the "flat topology". I clearly don't know how this is connected to the flat topology in the Grothendieck sense.

Comment: The only Zariski neighborhood of the closed point in a local scheme $X$ is $X$. So, $U=\mathrm{Spec\,}(R_P)$ and your condition just means that $S$ is stable under generalization.

Comment: @Laurent: Oh, that's a good point. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure if it's true in the non-Noetherian case, but if $R$ is Noetherian, then a subset $S$ of $\mathrm{Spec}(R)$ is (Zariski) open if and only if it is constructible (in the sense of the Stacks Project) and stable under generalization. 

Comment: Two people have said this now, so it is making me nervous, but isn't the term "stable under generization"?

Comment: I should probably stop before I upset some people, but seriously, the term is "generization." Look in Hartshorne or any textbook that talks about Zariski spaces or sober spaces or even PlanetMath: http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/Generization.html

Comment: @Matt: You are right. These points are not more general, but more generic. Also EGA talks about *générisations* (Ch. 0, 2.1.1). Somehow I always read it the wrong way, and probably I'm not the only one? There are several sources using "generalization", for example the Stacks Project http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0060 and many research papers.

Comment: Also, for the record, that second comment was a reply to a now deleted comment. I wasn't repeating myself unprovoked.